# Is "randomly" more appropriate than "haphazardly" to describe an accounting process?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In a draft of a business document (in the United States) explaining an accounting process, I see the word "haphazardly" used where I think "randomly" might be more appropriate.

Here's an example: *"We **haphazardly** selected 25 receipts generated in the month of July."*

To me, "haphazardly" implies a degree of carelessness or even recklessness in the process, which is definitely not intended by the authors, who only wish to say that the receipts were selected at random.

Am I correct that "randomly" would be a better word? Or is "haphazardly" also OK in this context?

Comment: If the "disorganized" nature of the action was intentional then you should prefer "random" over "haphazard".  (And there are probably better terms than "random".)

Comment: ("Haphazard" implies carelessness.)

Comment: It is possible that the selection process was not statistically random. Perhaps they meant *arbitrarily*?

Comment: @Hot Licks and Mick yes, process was probably not statistically random -- more likely arbitrary -- thank you!

Comment: It sounds to me like they intended the selection to be random, whether it was "statistically random* or not. I believe you are correct: randomly is a (much) more apt word choice.

Comment: Oops, I voted up your question and then realized you didn't share your attempts to figure it out on your own (an easy way to do this is to include definitions).  Do try to do that in future.

Comment: Assuming that this is a report of an audit process of some kind, a more common term is "sampled" without specific reference to how the sample is derived.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the separate dictionary definitions (Oxford Dictionaries - not OED) they do look remarkably similar:

***random*** adj. *made, done or happening without method or conscious decision*.

***haphazard*** adj *lacking any obvious principle of organisation*.

However, when you look more closely it is noticeable that the former is worded in such a way as would suggest a deliberate act, whilst the latter, beginning with the word *lacking*, suggests something less controlled.

Those are certainly the senses in which I would use the words, but it does not mean that they are not near synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

I won't repeat the definitions here, which others have given, but I will explain how people tend to go about making the choice among **haphazard, arbitrary** and **random** in general formal writing.  (I think that's what you wanted to know.)

I listed the three words in order of *planned-ness*, with **haphazard** being at the *least planned* end of the spectrum.  Strictly speaking, **arbitrary** might have been the correct word for the business document you read.  In a math journal, an author would probably be careful not to confuse **arbitrary** with **random**.  (And let's not get into *pseudorandom*!)

In more general formal writing, **random** would acceptable as a euphemism for **arbitrary**, which a general readership might connote with *not very well thought out*.

**Haphazard** is going to be connoted with *sloppy*.  People aren't likely to use it to describe a process they aren't criticizing.

Comment: Random also has a very specific meaning in accounting - or certainly the auditing of accounts. When I worked for one of the Big 4, we weren't allowed to say we took a random sample because of its very specific mathematical meaning.